# Data transfer into SQL

Tags: python, sql, json, django, django-views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
from .models import MyModel
import os


def display(request):
    json_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', './jsondata.json')
    try:
        with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            for item in data:
                my_model_instance = MyModel(end_year=item['end_year'], intensity=item['intensity'],
                                            sector=item['sector'], topic=item['topic'], insight=item['insight'],
                                            url=item['url'], region=item['region'], start_year=item['start_year'],
                                            impact=item['impact'], added=item['added'], published=item['published'],
                                            country=item['country'], relevance=item['relevance'], pestle=item['pestle'],
                                            source=item['source'], title=item['title'], likelihood=item['likelihood'])
            my_model_instance.save()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        data = []

    template_name = 'display'
    return render(request, template_name, {'data': data})
```

I am trying to transfer the data from JSON into SQL using Django.

Comment: It only saves the last row?

Comment: Into _SQL_? SQL is a _language_. You can't move data into a language.

Answer (score 3):

You save the item *outside* the `for` loop, so it will only save the last row, since at the end of the loop `my_model_instance` will point to the last item created.

We can make a list of items, and use [**`.bulk_create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to add all items to the database in *one* query:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
from .models import MyModel
import os

def display(request):
    json_file_path = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', './jsondata.json'
    )
    with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        my_models = [
            MyModel(
                end_year=item['end_year'],
                intensity=item['intensity'],
                sector=item['sector'],
                topic=item['topic'],
                insight=item['insight'],
                url=item['url'],
                region=item['region'],
                start_year=item['start_year'],
                impact=item['impact'],
                added=item['added'],
                published=item['published'],
                country=item['country'],
                relevance=item['relevance'],
                pestle=item['pestle'],
                source=item['source'],
                title=item['title'],
                likelihood=item['likelihood'],
            )
            for item in data
        ]
        MyModel.objects.bulk_create(my_models)

    template_name = 'display'
    return render(request, template_name, {'data': data})
```